Link problem of oatpp-openssl for openSSL 1.1.1.k
I am trying to use oatpp-openssl in my applicaitons, my OS is REHL8.8 and the openSSL version is 1.1.1k.
When I build oatpp-openssl, there is no problem of the static library, but I always get the link problem when I try to build an application, even the test suites in the release package of oatpp-openssl:
[100%] Linking CXX executable module-tests ../src/liboatpp-openssl.a(Connection.cpp.o):
In function `oatpp::openssl::Connection::ConnectionContext::init()': Connection.cpp:
(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `SSL_state' ../src/liboatpp-openssl.a(Connection.cpp.o):
In function `oatpp::openssl::Connection::ConnectionContext::initAsync()::HandshakeCoroutine::act()':
Connection.cpp:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `SSL_state'
collect2: error: ld returned 1
exit status make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/module-tests.dir/build.make:152:test/module-tests] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:142: test/CMakeFiles/module-tests.dir/all] Error 2 make: ***
[Makefile:146: all] Error 2

So do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?
